# VS2012 changes assembly location after adding the reference

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have a TFS Policy for VS2010, I want to use it in VS2012 also so I created a new project (a library targeting Framework 4.5) and started the migration, the problem is that VS2012 insist on changing the paths of my references, for example:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\PublicAssemblies\envdte.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Assemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.dll
```

VS2012 changes it to:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\envdte.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SDK SP1\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Assemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.dll
```

Is there a way to avoid this?, I added a HintPath to the .proj file with the full path but Im afraid it will not compile on the server if cant find the exact same path.

Comment: I'm facing similar problem...